# Dump MysqlDB and transfer it to FTP

Tags: mysql, windows, ftp

I had created a batch file

```
@echo off
echo Running dump...
CD c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
CALL mysqldump --user=1234 --password=aaaa dba1 --result-file="c:\Users_%DATE%.sql" 
echo Done!
```

and I dont know, how to transfer it to ftp;

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`ftp` command line utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687787%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

It is capable of using scripts (lists of commands from external files)

```
ftp -s:ftpcmd.dat your.ftp.server.com
```

Now you can either create this script file beforehand or make it on the fly from your batch file using `echo`.